# update column with json data involves array list

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-update

i have data in database table 1, column B as below in json format:

```
    {
  "Id": "Parent/A/1",
  "name": "test name",
  "items": [
    {
      "itemId": "Item 2",
      "serialNumbers": [
        "S1234"
      ],
      "count": 80
    }
  ],
  "links": []
}
```

I would like to update the value at parent, at child array.

1. when column A = 1 then update column B "name" to "test name new" , and
2. update column B "count" = 90 when "items", "itemId" = "Item 2"
3. update column B "serialNumbers" = S888 when "items", "itemId" = "Item 2"

i have simple SQL query like this, for non-jason value type of column:

```
UPDATE [dbo].1
SET colB = 'Item2'
WHERE colA = '1'
```

i am not sure what should be the query when involves, json data and array list.

Comment: sql server added

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: @Zhorov sql 2016, 17,19 any special if the query not supported at certain version?

Comment: What is the count of the items in the `items` and `serialNumbers` JSON arrays - always 1 or can vary? Thanks.

Comment: @Zhorov not always 1, as it is array.

Answer (score 0):

You may use two possible approaches to modify the stored JSON data:

- The first approach is to use `JSON_MODIFY()` function. In this situation you need to define an exact path expression that specifies the property to update.
- The second possible approach is to parse the stored JSON data and transform this JSON into a table using `OPENJSON()`. Then you can modify the table and transform it again into valid JSON using `FOR JSON PATH` and/or `FOR JSON AUTO`. The problem here is that you can't generate a valid JSON array of scalar values (`items` and `serialNumbers` JSON arrays in the example data). In this case you need to use some basic string manipulations and aggregations, using `CONCAT()` and `STRING_AGG()` functions.

The next solution (based on both approaches) may help you to find a solution to your problem. The solution requires SQL Server 2017+:

JSON and table:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{
   "Id":"Parent/A/1",
   "name":"test name",
   "items":[
      {
         "itemId":"Item 2",
         "serialNumbers":[
            "S1234",
            "S5678"
         ],
         "count":80
      },
      {
         "itemId":"Item 3",
         "serialNumbers":["S1234"],
         "count":80
      }
   ],
   "links":[
   ]
}'
CREATE TABLE Data (
   ColumnA int,
   ColumnB nvarchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO Data
   (ColumnA, ColumnB)
VALUES
   (1, @json),
   (2, @json)
```

Update statements:

```
UPDATE Data
SET ColumnB = JSON_MODIFY(ColumnB, '$.name', 'test new name')
WHERE ColumnA = 1

UPDATE Data
SET ColumnB = JSON_MODIFY(
   ColumnB, 
   '$.items', 
   (
      SELECT 
         itemId,
         JSON_QUERY(CASE 
            WHEN itemId = 'Item 2' THEN (
               SELECT CONCAT(N'[', STRING_AGG(N'"S8888"', N','), N']') 
               FROM OPENJSON(serialNumbers)
            ) 
            ELSE serialNumbers 
         END) AS serialNumbers,
         CASE WHEN itemId = 'Item 2' THEN 90 ELSE [count] END AS [count]
      FROM OPENJSON(ColumnB, '$.items') WITH (
         itemId nvarchar(10) '$.itemId',
         serialNumbers nvarchar(max) '$.serialNumbers' AS JSON,
         [count] int '$.count'
      )
      FOR JSON PATH
   )
)
WHERE ColumnA = 1
```

Result:

```
ColumnA ColumnB
1       {
        "Id":"Parent/A/1",
        "name":"test new name",
        "items":[{"itemId":"Item 2","serialNumbers":["S8888","S8888"],"count":90},{"itemId":"Item 3","serialNumbers":["S1234"],"count":80}],
        "links":[]
        }
2       {
        "Id":"Parent/A/1",
        "name":"test name",
        "items":[{"itemId":"Item 2","serialNumbers":["S1234","S5678"],"count":80},{"itemId":"Item 3","serialNumbers":["S1234"],"count":80}],
        "links":[]
        }
```